# Widget created through script from an external source

Tags: javascript, html, widget, external

Actually, I don't find a easy way to frame this question.

1. `http://www.a1000yoga.com/`
2. `http://www.voyzek.com/contact-us/`

I want to know how this widget is created only through script. I can see the html source files is saved somewhere else and it is called from server,  can someone clear me how these things work.

In these example, there is widget in the right bottom of the screen and the widget is not coming from same website. Once someone signing up like [`Zopim chat`](https://www.zopim.com/), [Live Chat](https://my.livechatinc.com/) a script file is generated automatically and it is send to registered email, once we copy and paste it to our site, the widget comes automatically.

Sorry, I don't have reputation to brief my question, any response will be much helpful.